# ReactJS Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs

i develop google signIn in react. For learn how do realises signIn and learn any conceptions of reactjs.
I get \\\/// error:

```
import {useState, useCallback} from 'react'

export const useGLogIn = props => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setLogIn] = useState(false)

  const login = useCallback(async ({
    onSuccess, onFailure, onFinish
  }) => {
    console.log(onSuccess, onFailure, onFinish);
  }, [])

  return {login}
}
```

Here which is error?

I use React.Component and call hook inside method login which calls when i click Button

```
login() {
  const {login} = useGLogIn(this.props)
}
```

```
<button onClick={this.login}>Login With Google </button>
```

> Thanks. To All

Comment: `login` is not a function component. Can you share your component where you have the `button` element?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a hook within a class component (based on your usage of `this.login`). This isn't allowed, as the error states. Your only option if you want to use the hook is to convert the class component to a functional component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Hooks can only be used within functional components (not a component that extends `React.Component`)

You either need to change the component with the login method to a functional component, or not use hooks

**Resources**

- [Using the state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's documentation on this error here, https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

In general, `hook` is a function, so you should be able to define it as in most of the functional cases (Your usage is right). However, if it ever needs to be invoked, I believe it needs to be inside the scope of react function components. https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

The idea of the `hook` to me is like a `trait` that facilitates you calling the react component method. Which means, the hook is almost useless if declared outside the scope of react component.

In order to test your custom hook, either you embed it inside a function component or you can use some library, https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library.